# Angular (4) send an object from one component to a sibling

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 2+ so I realize I might be going about this the wrong way.
I have two components who are siblings. When I click on a "link" in one it redirects to another controller. I want to pass on the object to the component that I am landing on.

This is what I have done so far.

In the first component (building list) I have an event.

```
public onClick_building(building: Building) {

  this._building.addBuilding(building);

  this._router.navigate(['/sam/checklistsam']);
}
```

addBuilding is in a service (building service)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { ServerService } from './../server-service/server.service';
import { Building } from '../../interfaces/building';
import { FranchiseBuildingFilter } from '../../interfaces/franchise-building-filter';



@Injectable()
export class BuildingService {

  public newBuildingIdSubject: Subject<Building> = new Subject<Building>();

  private _url = 'building/';

  constructor(private http: Http, private _server: ServerService) { }

  public addBuilding(building) {
    this.newBuildingIdSubject.next(building);
  }
}
```

Then I call for it in component (work with single building page) that I am sent to.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Building } from '../../../interfaces/building';

import { BuildingService } from '../../../services/building-
service/building.service';
import { ServerService } from '../../../services/server-service/server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checklist',
  templateUrl: './checklist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checklist.component.css'],
  providers: [BuildingService, ServerService]
})
export class ChecklistComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  public building: Building;

  constructor(private _building: BuildingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._building.newBuildingIdSubject.subscribe(res => {
    this.building = res;
  });
}
```

How ever this.building is undefined.
When I am debugging it doesn't go in to subscribe.

Is there another way to do this or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need more detail. Can you add the @Component annotation part of your components? Where do you provide this service? How do you inject it? How do you know it's undefined?

Comment: are you injecting your `service` in your `component`?

Comment: i guess what you are looking for is passing data between components check this [link-question2](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: I added the "full" service and component.

Comment: It has the object when it is in the service. The object is undefined when I try to fetch it from the controller it is sent to. I have checked it by using debugger; after newBuildingIdSubject.subscribe. I have also tried to set debugger inside newBuildingIdSubject.subscribe but it doesn't just runs past it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems, first of all, your shared service isn't a singleton, so basically it's not a shared service at all. You have provided it in providers array on component level, which means that you have separate instances of services in your components.

You should only add the service as provider in NgModule if you want it as a singleton:

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ BuildingService ] // here!
})
```

so remove it from components. Also remove `ServerService` if it's a similar situation.

```ts
@Component({
  ...
  // providers: [BuildingService, ServerService] <-- Remove
})
```

Second problem, when we have this fixed, is that a `Subject` won't work here. Subscription of a `Subject` is only fired when it gets an `next()`. But as you are calling `next()` before navigating to the sibling component, it won't fire in your sibling, since the `next()` was already done in the other component before navigating.

You could use a `BehaviorSubject` that always emits when there is a subscriber.

```ts
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

public newBuildingIdSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Building>(null);
```

`BehaviorSubject` needs an initial value, so make the appropriate initial value you want :)

Comment: Hi, I am not getting it to work. I am thinking that I hade to place BuildingService in the closest common module? If I understand this correct. I have removed the providers in the component. But I now get the error Cannot read property 'addBuilding' of undefined. I feel link I am missing something.

Comment: Well you have injected the service in constructors though, right? Sounds like you are not doing that?

Comment: Thank you! That was what I forgot. The value is saved to newBuildingIdSubject. How ever I still get undefined in this.building.

     `this.subscription = this._bs.newBuildingSubject
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.building = res;
          });`

Comment: Re surely now having as a singleton service? It should work as is if you provide the service on module level. And a `BehaviorSubject` requires a default value, so it shouldn't be undefined anyhow.

Comment: Sorry, I was not explaining it correctly. The data is there (if i console.log(res) what is in  res) but it doesn't write it to this.building. Building is an interface. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Naah, an interface shouldnt be an issue, since it doesn't exist on runtime. How do you determine that it's not assigned to building? Are you console logging inside subscribe after assigning value?

Comment: Yes, like this:
`this.subscription = this._bs.newBuildingSubject
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.building = <Building>res;
            console.log(res);
          });`

Comment: Well you are not console logging building, so how do you know the value isn't there? :)

Comment: Sorry, pasted old code. But it just started working. I didn't change anything.
Maybe it was cached or something.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I now realized that I did change something. :)
I added <Building> before res. That did the final trick.